# T-Test in Excel 2016 with Data Analysis

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm trying to do a t-test in Excel but I'm not sure how to use it properly.
I got seven different methods for calculating a company's value. For each method, I do an estimation of the value and therefore get an (absolute) deviation from the actual value in percent (so zero is the best estimation and the higher the deviation gets, the worse the result). The dataset comprises 300 companies.
My objective is to compare each of the seven methods pairwise against each other to find out which is the best one.

Which is the right t-test in the data analysis add-in in excel? There are three different t-tests (Paired Two Sample for Means, Two-Sample Assuming Equal Variances, Two-Sample assuming unequal Variances). What are the differences? What assumption regarding the variances can I make?

Thank you!

Comment: What have you tried? What have you read/learned about it? Looking [around online](http://www.statisticshowto.com/how-to-do-a-t-test-in-excel/) I found [various](http://www.excel-easy.com/examples/t-test.html) descriptions of [t tests](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/T-TEST-function-d4e08ec3-c545-485f-962e-276f7cbed055) for Excel.

Comment: From what I understand, the Paired Two Sample For Means is mainly used for before / after kind of tests which wouldn't fit mine since I want to compare two different methods estimating the price of a company. There's no before / after but it's an estimation concerning the same company.
The Two-Sample assuming (UN)equal Variances tests are used for different groups which is also not true for mine as I always compare two estimations for the same company against each other.
To sum it up, I see no reason for choosing the one or the other test ...

Comment: From the wording of your question, it's not clear that you need a t-test.  How are you estimating the value with the seven methods, and where are you getting the "actual value"?  If you have an accurate number for the value of a company, then the seven methods can be ranked by comparing each one's estimate to the actual value of the company.

Comment: SOrry if I didn't make it clear. Let's just say there are seven different methods of estimating a value (which I actually know, because it's just the price of the stock I took from Thomson Reuters). Afterwards, I want to see which method gave me the lowest deviation from the actual value. I calculate an average for all the 300 companies and for every method.
In the end I get an average estimation error of 0.29 for method 1, 0.34 for method 2, 0.33 for method 3 and so on.
Now I want to see if those differences are statistically significant. And my purpose was to use the t-test for that,wrong?

Comment: I think it is inevitable to do a Wilcoxon signed-ranks test. Found a nice excel add-in to conduct those tests. If anyone is interested, look at this: http://www.real-statistics.com/non-parametric-tests/wilcoxon-rank-sum-test/ there's a free download link for the add-in.